# How to Generate Controller in Symfony 3.0?

Tags: symfony

Hope you are all fine, I am a beginner trying to learn Symfony 3.0, so I want to generate my controller in a folder called Bundles, but it is not created, here is the command I taped :

```
php bin/console generate:controller
```

And this is fine, when I tape the controller name, that was what I wrote :

```
?[32mController name?[39m: Bundles/FrontBundle
```

But their answer is :

```
?[37;41m The controller name must contain a : ("Bundles/FrontBundle" 
given, expecting something like AcmeBlogBundle:Post) ?[39;49m
```

I don't know if I have to do something before this to noy have such error.
Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because controller name should be a combination of `BundleName:ControllerName` and you have provided a relative path to your bundle. If that doesn't work make sure you have your autloading properly setup and Symfony knows about your bundle

Answer (score 0):

According to his [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_controller.html) you should use the shortcut notation when you are declaring a controller, entity, etc.

also you need to read the output of the command.

> Welcome to the Symfony controller generator
>
> Every page, and even sections of a page, are rendered by a controller.
>   This command helps you generate them easily.
>
> First, you need to give the controller name you want to generate. **You
>   must use the shortcut notation like *AcmeBlogBundle:Post***
>
> Controller name: BundleNameEndingBundle:ControllerName